# Does all Pending Intent is deleted after boot in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

Can't I retrieve it again using Request ID?

like using:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, RequestID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

PS: I have all pendingExtra's in PendingIntent, else I have to fetch from database again!

Comment: That is code that is used to build a PI. But your question is not related to constructing, it's about retrieving. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does all Pending Intent is deleted after boot in android?

Yes. They are only held in RAM, in a core OS process.

> Can't I retrieve it again using Request ID?

Not after a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all PendingIntents will be deleted after you reboot. But you can recreate them when the phone is booted up. [This tutorial here](http://javatechig.com/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android) does a pretty good job of explaining how to deal with bootup listeners.

Define a class `DeviceBootReceiver` as follows, which will run your code (creating PendingIntents, or whatever else you want) when the device has been booted.:

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class DeviceBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            // Do your thing in here
        }
    }
}
```

And don't forget to (a) get permission and (b) declare this receiver in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application ...>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    ...

    <receiver android:name=".DeviceBootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Comment: Thank you.. :) im again fetching from database and creating alarm :(

Comment: Then you'll love the tutorial I linked -- it's precisely about creating alarms.